# How to get audio output on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, sound, headphones, audio-jack

I'm trying to get audio output on my Ubuntu server. The audio device is a simple headphone on the audio-jack.

I've tried setting the defaults in alsa, and even in pulseaudio. I'm also testing to make sure it works by playing an audio file with mpv. But so far I haven't managed to get any audio output to work at all.

Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server as my OS. The question is about audio

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, I believe